# How to invoke a closure within a function when counting number of times function is invoked

Tags: javascript

I want to count the number of times a function is called on click.  I have this so far but its not quite working.  Can anyone help with this?

```
function test(){
    var count = (function({
        var i = 0;
        return function(){
           return i += 1;
        }
     })();

   if(count() == 2){
     // do this
   }

}
```

Invoke the function like so:

```
<select onclick="javascript: test();">
```

It looks like the count function isn't being invoked properly.  How can I invoke the function and perform an operation on it?  I want to perform logic at certain numbers of clicks.

Comment: You seem to be vastly overcomplicating this - why not just put the `count` variable outside of the `test` function and increment it on it being called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a closure to wrap the call.

```js
function countUsage(methodToWrap, methodContext) {
  const
    wrapContext = methodContext || this;
  let
    count = 0;
  
  // Return a method, this is the wrapped call.
  return function methodWrapper() {
    // Increase the counter by 1.
    count++;
    // Call the original method with the arguments.
    methodToWrap.apply(wrapContext, arguments);
    // Log the number of times the method was called.
    console.log(`The method has been called ${count} times`); 
  }
}

function methodToWrap(text) {
  console.log(`Log line ${text}`);
}

function sumToWrap(a, b) {
  console.log(`Sum of ${a} + ${b} = ${a+b}`);
}

const
  wrappedLog = countUsage(methodToWrap),
  wrappedSum = countUsage(sumToWrap);

// For these three calls you will see the count is increased with each call.
wrappedLog('hello');
wrappedLog('how');
wrappedLog('are you');

// This will result in a log line that there has been 1 call as it is a different method.
wrappedSum(3, 4);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is way to complex for what the OP was hoping and is not using their language version (ES5 vs ES6+)

Comment: If he has only one method where we wants to keep count, then yes, this may be too complicated. However if he has multiple methods that need to keep track of their usage, this is a nice reusable pattern. As for the ES6, you can replace all the `const` and `let` for `var` and it still works just as well.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var count = 0;
function test(){
   count++;
   if(count == 2){
     // do this
     console.log('do something');
   }
}
```

```html
<label onclick="javascript: test();">Test</label>
```

Take a variable and increment on number of click and do your operation.

Answer (score -2):

Does this work for you?

```js
    var i = 0;
    function test(){
        var count = (function() {
            return function(){
               return i += 1;
            }
         })();
       if(count() == 2){
         console.log('reached goal')
         // do this
       }
    
      alert('current count' +i)
    
    }
```

```html
<select onclick="test()"><option>select</option></select>
```

And on your item just:

```
onlick="test()"
```

You generally had brackets in the wrong place etc and was always setting the value to 0.

Comment: To the person who negged, you should always state a REASON. Nobody is going to learn by just negging. Alternatively edit the post or suggest an improvement.